# Performance Comparision of linq 2sql and Ado.net Entity Framework with stored Procedure?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

Hi I am devloping the a asp.net site which will have lots of user online at a time. I am writing very efficient stored procedure for it. Which ORM tool should I use?

Ado.net entity framework or linq2sql?

Performance is needed as our requirement is to load every page in 4 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi i guess you needed to do a quick search in older stackoverflow questions.

And here is what i found ... [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257016/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework-performance) i guess these would help you to decide what would you choose ;)

Also you may visit those pages :
 1- [Entity Framework vs LINQ TO SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/11/06/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql.aspx)
 2- [ADO.NET Entity Framework Performance Comparison](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/03/27/ado-net-entity-framework-performance-comparison.aspx)
 3- [LINQ to Entities vs. LINQ to SQL - What should I use and when?](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/adoef_vs_linqsql.htm)