# Why LINQ 2 sql gives better perfomance?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I read in some article that LINQ to SQL gives better performance when executing stored procedure than Entity framework. Any obvious reasons for it?

Comment: Do you have a **link** to that article??

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257016/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework-performance

Comment: No this isn't a duplicate, the other article discusses general Entity Framework versus Linq to sql, not specific the stored procedure performance.

Comment: yes.. this is specific to the execution of stored procedures. I do not have that link with me now. It was some whrere in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a performance difference, in L2S you can make your sproc return a list of l2s objects which are going to be tracked for changes. For large result sets this could be a severe performance hit, if you're not going to change these objects.

I don't know how Entity Framework handles these kind of situations.

In L2S you can also turn this behaviour off in your datacontext. (ObjectTrackingEnabled = false)