# Is anyone using entity framework? It has its own linq-to-sql implementation?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

Where can I see the documenation for entity framework, specifically where it has all the features of linq-to-sql? Is the database setup the same or just the syntax is the same to query over the objects, but mapping the db to models is different?

Any simple tutorials that you guys can suggest? nothing offical from MS, something from a real developer would be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't continue to support LINQ to SQL ,they planed to EF replaces LINQ to SQL,because LINQ to SQL has many limitatins.
EF instead has more features, and is more powerful than LINQ to SQL, it can work with more providers, works with Oracle, My SQL and even SQL Lite... EF has all Linq features and more I guess...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257016/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework-performance